# Read a gyroscope value with the I2c bus

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, i2c, gyroscope

Product : https://www.adafruit.com/product/2020

datasheet: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/LSM9DS0.pdf

I'm student and it's the first time for me to use I2c bus. I am trying to read the basic gyroscope value. I wasted a part of my life to understand how the I2c work. But after reading the datasheet and made my own script.
My values are stuck there. Nothing move and I don't know why.

```
Rotation in X-Axis : -1087
Rotation in Y-Axis : -28797
Rotation in Z-Axis : -15032
```

Here is my script. Someone can help me to solve it? I'm working with a beagle bone black.

```
import smbus
import time


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# 0x6b adress (found with i2cdetect), 0x20 register (found with the data sheet), CTRL_REG1_G(20h)
bus.write_byte_data(0x6b, 0x20, 0x0F)

bus.write_byte_data(0x6b, 0x23, 0x30)

time.sleep(0.5)


data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x08)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x09)


xGyro = data1 * 256 + data0
if xGyro > 32767 :
    xGyro -= 65536

data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x0A)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x0B)


yGyro = data1 * 256 + data0
if yGyro > 32767 :
    yGyro -= 65536


data0 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x0C)
data1 = bus.read_byte_data(0x6b, 0x0D)

zGyro = data1 * 256 + data0
if zGyro > 32767 :
    zGyro -= 65536


print "Rotation in X-Axis : %d" %xGyro
print "Rotation in Y-Axis : %d" %yGyro
print "Rotation in Z-Axis : %d" %zGyro
```

Comment: Can you read the `WHO_AM_I_G (0Fh)` register correctly? That would be the first thing I'd try, since it returns a constant.

Comment: Also it seems to me that you're reading from the wrong addresses. The gyroscope output registers are at 0x28...0x2D (section 8.9 - 8.11 in the datasheet). Addresses 0x08..0x0D are reserved when accessing the gyroscope submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/LSM9DS0.pdf), the LSM9DS0 contains 2 submodules: one containing accelerometer and compass, the other containing the gyroscope. Each of the submodules is located at a different address, determined by the state of `SA0_XM` and `SA0_G` pins.

[image: Tables 15 and 16 from the datasheet]

On the [Adafruit module](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/18546) those pins are pulled high, so according to tables 15 and 16 in the datasheet:

- accelerometer and compass are at address `0x1d` (`00011101`)
- gyroscope is at address `0x6b` (`01101011`)

Based on this, it appears you're accessing the correct address. It also means that near the beginning of your script, you should define a few constants, such as

```
ACCEL_ADDRESS = 0x1d
GYRO_ADDRESS = 0x6b
```

and use those instead of copying the magic number all around your code.

---

Now the register addresses. Since there are two different devices, there's a good chance that each exposes a different set of registers. Indeed, table 17 shows this to be the case, albeit somewhat indirectly. The important part is the column titled "Slave Address", which refers either to table 15 (accelerometer an compass) or table 16 (gyro). (The symbolic names of the registers might help you tell the difference in some cases, since they often have suffix `M` (former) or `G` (latter), but not always).

[image: Table 17]

And herein lies your problem. For a gyroscope, the measurements are in registers at addresses 0x28..0x2d

[image: Gyroscope registers]

yet you are reading from `0x08..0x0d`, which are reserved in the gyroscope module (getting some fixed nonsense as a result of reading that would not be unexpected).

You seem to have gotten the control registers `CTRL_REG1_G` and `CTRL_REG4_G` correctly.

Of course, just as with the addresses, you should have constants defined for all the registers you want to use:

```
CTRL_REG1_G = 0x20
CTRL_REG4_G = 0x23
OUT_X_L_G = 0x28
OUT_X_H_G = 0x29
```

and so on...

---

As an aside, the first thing I would try, before actually reading the measured values, would be reading the device identification register, in this case `WHO_AM_I_G` (0x0F).

[image: Device identification register]

Since this register returns a constant, it's a good way to validate you're talking with the right device, and that the communication works correctly.

---

One more: don't copy-paste code around, use functions instead.

For example the first step of refactoring could yield something like:

```
def read_int16(bus, device, register):
    lsb = bus.read_byte_data(device, register)
    msb = bus.read_byte_data(device, register + 1)

    result = msb * 256 + lsb
    return (result - 65536) if (result > 32767) else result


xGyro = read_int16(bus, GYRO_ADDRESS, OUT_X_L_G)
yGyro = read_int16(bus, GYRO_ADDRESS, OUT_Y_L_G)
zGyro = read_int16(bus, GYRO_ADDRESS, OUT_Z_L_G)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many i2c publications where you can find out how it works. Also most gyro and mems devices basically explain it in their data sheets also. But basically it is two wires which have logic high and logic low states. The messages are usually sent in 8 bit segments. To send a segment the clock wire goes low then the data is transitioned to the level which is to be sent. The data wire must be stable and then clock goes high. The data level when clock goes high is the bit 0 (data low) or 1 (data high). The devices 8 bit address is sent first (really 7 bit address, the last bit is to signal read or write). Usually to write you send read first then interrupt followed by write. When reading, after device address is sent, the next 8 or 16 bits are register address. Then the device will send information. Writing is similar. Some mems device have fifo register and interrupts which can be a little different. See your respective data sheets for details.

Comment: Also I don't use python. So your on your own there using the mcu and flashing it.

Comment: IMHO this simply does not address the OP's problem.

Comment: The asker appears to have no clue where to start solving their problem. To me a basic understanding of i2c is necessary. I can see to a beginner not used to data sheets, that the timing and rise fall time stuff can maybe be intimidating. I thought by attempting to give a brief description of what is going on in common words might jump start some understanding. I'm not familiar with beaglebone or it's python based assembler/compiler, it's i2c hardware and control or python in general. At the time no one had answered and I didn't think the question was that bad.

Comment: I think given other answers mine is still relevant and even useful, though could be made more clear, correct to i2c standard etc. But it's relevance is certainly there, I think.

Comment: Your answer seems to focus more on python style and cleanliness of code, I think this is irrelevant. But stackxchange has taken towards programming methodology rather than functional things like solving hardware problems (I don't like this aspect of stackexchange). So I guess you are ultimately correct but I'll use my vote here while I still have one (already banned from asking questions).